# How to programmatically configure "Allow authentication without the client secret" in WSO2 IS 5.10.0 for a service provider?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using an in-premises installation of WSO2 IS 5.10.0 as well as ansible playbook scripts to configure it to a target state. This target state involves at least one application (service provider). In so far we have managed to do all our configuration using administration APIs.

Specifically for the service provider we have introduced it using this endpoint: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/application-rest-api/#/Applications/createApplication

The problem is that we want to use the service provider without our UI webpage to be aware of the OAUTH 2.0 client secret. We realized this was possible by enabling the flag under `Service Providers > Edit > Inbound Authentication Configuration > OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration > Allow authentication without the client secret`. It turns out that even though we can enable/disable this feature from the administration dashboard there is no way to do it programmatically using an endpoint in the REST service for service providers (part of which is the endpoint I cited above).

We figured out that one way it to manually set up a WSO2 instance, enable the flag and then export the service provider in XML. Which would allow us to use this endpoint afterwards: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/application-rest-api/#/Applications/importApplication

*The question is the following; Is there is a better way to enable this flag programmatically or is this a feature not yet supported by the Application Management API?*

For reference the application management API: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/application-rest-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Inbound Protocols-OAuth/OIDC PUT operationn](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/application-rest-api/#/Inbound%20Protocols%20-%20OAuth%20%2F%20OIDC/updateInboundOAuthConfiguration) to update oidc service provider's configurations. You need to ebable or disable `publicClient` attribute. This will update `Allow authentication without the client secret` attribute

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip @piraveena-paralogarajah. I will try it out and accept your answer if it works!

Comment: It did finally work as you said, it was not obvious that the public client property reflected the option I was going for. The documentation is a little bit vague when it comes to this but thankfully your input saved me. Worth noting in my case it was easier to use this property from the start when I was creating the identity provider application using the POST endpoint.